# NPM package component gives an error if reexported in another library

Tags: reactjs, npm, styled-components, rollupjs

I have a component library and one of our components uses `react-toggle` library. When I try to use our component in another app I get the error `Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.` I am using rollup as a bundler, here's the configuration.

```
import path from 'path';
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';
import filesize from 'rollup-plugin-filesize';
import localResolve from 'rollup-plugin-local-resolve';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy';
import pkg from './package.json';

const SOURCE_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const INPUT_FILE_PATH = `${SOURCE_DIR}/index.ts`;
const OUTPUT_NAME = 'InPlayerUI';
const extensions = ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'];

const GLOBALS = {
  react: 'React',
  'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
  'styled-components': 'styled-components',
};

const PLUGINS = [
  image(),
  resolve({
    mainFields: ['module', 'main', 'jsnext:main', 'browser'],
    extensions,
  }),
  commonjs({ include: ['node_modules/**'] }),
  babel({
    include: ['src/**/*'],
    exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    babelHelpers: 'bundled',
    extensions,
  }),
  localResolve(),
  terser(),
  filesize(),
  copy({
    targets: [{ src: './index.d.ts', dest: 'dist' }],
  }),
];

const EXTERNAL = ['react', 'react-dom', 'styled-components'];

const OUTPUT_DATA = [
  {
    file: pkg.browser,
    format: 'umd',
  },
  {
    file: pkg.main,
    format: 'cjs',
  },
  {
    file: pkg.module,
    format: 'es',
  },
];

const config = OUTPUT_DATA.map(({ file, format }) => ({
  input: INPUT_FILE_PATH,
  output: {
    file,
    format,
    name: OUTPUT_NAME,
    globals: GLOBALS,
  },
  external: EXTERNAL,
  plugins: PLUGINS,
}));

export default config;
```

and the `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "@inplayer-org/inplayer-ui",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "version": "2.0.4",
  "author": "InPlayer",
  "description": "InPlayer React UI Components",
  "main": "dist/inplayer-ui.cjs.js",
  "module": "dist/inplayer-ui.esm.js",
  "browser": "dist/inplayer-ui.umd.js",
  "jsnext:main": "dist/inplayer-ui.esm.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/inplayer-org/inplayer-ui"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/inplayer-org/inplayer-ui/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/inplayer-org/inplayer-ui#readme",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "yarn run storybook",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 3001",
    "build:storybook": "build-storybook -c .storybook -o docs",
    "clean:dist": "rimraf ./dist",
    "build": "yarn run clean:dist && npx rollup -c",
    "lint": "eslint '*/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}' --quiet --fix",
    "lint:watch": "esw -w src/**",
    "prepublishOnly": "yarn build",
    "lint:style": "stylelint -- \"./src/**/*.js\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-toggle": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-classes": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.10.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^14.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-image": "^2.0.5",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^8.4.0",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-info": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.3.19",
    "@types/dompurify": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.157",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.43",
    "@types/react-dates": "^17.1.13",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-toggle": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "3.7.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "3.7.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "dompurify": "^2.0.12",
    "eslint": "^7.5.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.0.8",
    "eslint-watch": "^7.0.0",
    "html-react-parser": "^0.13.0",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "polished": "^3.6.5",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "rc-progress": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dates": "^21.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
    "react-paginate": "^6.3.2",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-copy": "^3.3.0",
    "rollup-plugin-filesize": "^9.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-local-resolve": "^1.0.7",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^6.1.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
    "styled-components-modifiers": "^1.2.5",
    "styled-tools": "^1.7.2",
    "stylelint": "^13.6.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^20.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-styled-components": "^0.1.1",
    "stylelint-processor-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  }
}
```

This is the component

```
import React, { ChangeEvent } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Toggle from 'react-toggle';
import SwitchWrapper from './SwitchWrapper';
import Label from '../Label';

type SwitchProps = {
  /**
   * Whether the switch is checked or not
   */
  checked: boolean;
  /**
   * Disable switch
   */
  disabled?: boolean;
  /**
   * Id
   */
  id: string;
  /**
   * Switch label
   */
  label: string;
  /**
   * Function executed when the switch value changes
   */
  onChange: (checked: boolean) => void;
};

const MarginLeftLabel = styled(Label)`
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
`;

const Switch = ({ id, checked, label, disabled = false, onChange }: SwitchProps) => {
  const onToggleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.target) {
      onChange(e.target.checked);
    }
  };

  return (
    <SwitchWrapper>
      <MarginLeftLabel disabled={disabled} htmlFor={id}>
        {label}
      </MarginLeftLabel>
      <Toggle
        id={id}
        disabled={disabled}
        checked={checked}
        onChange={onToggleChange}
        icons={false}
      />
    </SwitchWrapper>
  );
};

export default Switch;
```

I have seen some suggestions that the import could be wrong but I've made sure it isn't and if I use `react-toggle` directly in another app it works.

Note: I've tried using different npm packages and reexport components from them, it works fine, so I suppose it has something to do with `react-toggle` itself.

Comment: maybe this can help https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13445#issuecomment-414389398

Comment: I've seen this already, but as you can see I export a component as a function correctly and the `Toggle` component should be correctly exported because I've used it directly in an app.